# Is the result of strcmp the same on all machines and compilers?

Tags: c, string

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{   
    int n = strcmp("hello","help");
    printf("%d\n", n ) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

> -1

Does the value for this program have to be the same on all machines or different compilers?

In other words can this return value take on different values for the same program when run on different compilers or different machines?

Comment: @MitchWheat The standard only guarantees the sign of the result, not its value. It would be permissible for an implementation to return -6 or -45 instead.

Comment: check out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strcmp.htm

Comment: @MitchWheat: The C99 Standard, 7.21.4.2 (The strcmp function) says `The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2.` - For anything before C99, query the respective standard.

Comment: If it is standard then it should have returned same set of fixed values. But check out my link above

Comment: It should return the same thing everywhere, but the *thing* one should consider is what is specified (`<0`, `0`, `>0`), not the precise value.

Comment: This is actually a really good question, it's just not obvious at first. It is not a dup of the question listed and the close reason `recommend or find a tool, library` does not make any sense at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not have to return `-1` but it does have to return a value less than zero(*if we assume an ASCII character set*), the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `7.21.4.2` *The strcmp function* says:

> The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero,
>   accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2.

and I can get `clang` to return either `-1`(*[live example with -O3](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4c8ea1aad3fb5b6)*) or `-4`(*[live example with -O0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ede991a25fc21af)*) depending on the optimization level.

With `-O3` or even `-O1` it looks like `clang` is not emitting a call to `strcmp` at all will just do a:

```
movl    $-1, %esi
```

`clang` is probably using *builtin* functions to optimize here similar to [gcc's builtin](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) and in fact I can only get `gcc` to emit a call to `strcmp` in this case using `-fno-builtin`.

Important to note the standard does not guarantee the order of alphabetic characters, although it does say that numeric characters should be sequential from section `5.2.1` *Character sets* paragraph *3* says:

> [...]In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
>   value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.[...]

So differing character sets can also lead to different results on different platforms, we can easily see that comparing [ASCII and EBCDIC](http://natural-innovations.com/computing/asciiebcdic.html). In `ASCII` the capital letters come before the lower case but it is the opposite in `EBCDIC`.

Comment: Good answer, but what `strcmp` returns, doesn't depend on your compiler, but on your `libc`.

Comment: @mafso that is assuming a call to `strcmp` is ever emitted which is not the case with any optimization turned on. I am guessing this is `gcc` [builtin functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Comment: What I meant to say was that I guess it must be similar to `gcc` builtins but I can not find a `clang` doc that covers this.

Comment: Since you mention it, where, exactly, does the standard say the result needs to be less than zero for those particular strings? It says to return less than zero when the first string is less than the second, but where does it define how to compare strings, or even that `'l'` is less than `'p'`? Do we take it by convention that the letters are ordered alphabetically, or does the standard mandate it? I only see it defining the relative order of the digit characters (in 5.2.1/3).

Answer (score 2):

Standard library only guarantees you, about `0` (compared correctly), lesser than `0`(could be `-1`, `-10`) and greater than `0`(could be `1`, `10`, `100`).

So yes you may get different values.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value has been defined by the C standard.  So, all compilers and different machines should return the same value on same strings.